# Ajax post model to controller action

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

In mvc4 i am trying to Post model data from view to controller using **Jquery Ajax** but don't now what's wrong with this code can any one help me in this matter.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#save").click(function () {
            $("#content").html("<b>Please Wait...</b>");
            var dataObject = {
                empid: 1,
                EmployeeName: "rizwan",
                Address: "lahore",
                Country: "pakistan",
                Salary: "35000.00",
                DepartmentName: "Field"
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/Index",
                data: dataObject,
                success: function (data)
                { 
                    $("#empname").val(''),
                    $("#empadd").val(''),
                    $("#empcountry").val(''),
                    $("#empsalary").val(''),
                    $("#empdeptname").val(''),
                    $("#content").html("<div class='success'>"+data+"</div>")
                },
                error: function (ehr)
                {
                    $("#content").html("<div class='failed'>Error! Please try again</div>");
                },
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is my controller action code who just receive the value of object and save into database 
**Problem is that i failed to receive values at controller action side.**
Please help me.....

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(userview dataObject)
{         
    department dept = new department();
    employee emp = new employee();
    string message = "";
    try
    {
        emp.employeeName = dataObject.EmployeeName;
        emp.address = dataObject.Address;
        emp.country = dataObject.Country;
        emp.salary = dataObject.Salary;
        dept.departmentName = dataObject.DepartmentName;
        db.employees.Add(emp);
        db.departments.Add(dept);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
         message = "Error! Please try again";
    }
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return new JsonResult { Data = message, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
    ViewBag.message = message;
    return View();
}
```

This is my model class

```
   public class userview
    {

        public int empId { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public decimal Salary { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; }


    }
```

Comment: Not related, but do not include both the unminified and minified versions of the same file

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the browser console?

Comment: The values are not receiving at controller action side when we hit the save button even i exclude the unminified, i keep only one minified versions file

Comment: Could you post the Model class?  I mean the userview class.

Comment: public userview(){ }

Comment: you have salary property as decimal in userview model but you are passing salary as string from javascript object.

Comment: then how would i manage decimal in this scenario Kartikeya

Comment: Can you get the post request from dev console/fiddler and post here?

Answer (score 0):

Try using  **JSON.stringify**

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/Index",
                data: JSON.stringify(dataObject), //Here is the change
                success: function (data)
                { 
                    $("#empname").val(''),
                    $("#empadd").val(''),
                    $("#empcountry").val(''),
                    $("#empsalary").val(''),
                    $("#empdeptname").val(''),
                    $("#content").html("<div class='success'>"+data+"</div>")
                },
                error: function (ehr)
                {
                    $("#content").html("<div class='failed'>Error! Please try again</div>");
                },
            })
```

Comment: Yes i try JSON.stringify(dataObject), but still i am receiving same issue

Comment: Has your Model "userview" a parameter-less constructor? Sometimes, adding an empty constructor makes the modelbinder work. Not really sure why is this.

Comment: Parameter-less or parametric

Answer (score 0):

You can implement BindModel yourself! get the json string and deserialize to your entity.

```
public class JsonBinder<T> : System.Web.Mvc.IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream))
        {
            //set stream position 0, maybe previous action already read the stream.
            controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
            string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(json) == false)
            {
                JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                object jsonData = serializer.DeserializeObject(json);
                return serializer.Deserialize<T>(json);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and set the JsonBinder to the post method like

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index([ModelBinder(typeof(JsonBinder<userview>))] userview dataObject)
{
}
```

the other solution

I found that you could set DataContract to the class of Model, and set DataMember to the Properties of the class.

edit the class like this

```
[DataContract]
public class userview
{
    [DataMember]
    public int empId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Country { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
}
```

and you should add library reference "System.Runtime.Serialization"

Hope it works for you.